# SQL Timeout exception: Due to a connection issue? Or a query/command taking too long?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I've been trying to debug an issue for a little while in an app I work on.

So far, I think that the following exception indicates an issue with the SqlClient being able to actually *connect* to the SQL Server, and not a timeout issue with a command/query. We're using EF 4.0 (connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2), and the only clue I have that suggests that this is a connect vs. execution issue is the *EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf* at the bottom of the stack.

**Based on the stack trace that follows, is this an issue with the client simply connecting to SQL? Or is this what a "execution timed out" exception looks like, too?**

```
TIME OCCURRED: 8/15/2013 1:56:11 AM
MESSAGE: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
SOURCE: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
STACK TRACE:
------------
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean& marsCapable)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginWithFailover(Boolean useFailoverHost, ServerInfo primaryServerInfo, String failoverHost, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
TARGET SITE: Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring while trying to open the connection. It appears that the server is contactable, otherwise you'd get a different error, but it's not responding to the connection.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought, it'd be nice if the messages in the exception indicated this.

Comment: @AndrewTheken, you're not kidding on that one. Often times, if it's not T-SQL related, the error messages from SQL Server are at best, useless.